# Cant access session in constructor Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, session

My function is here, `var_dump` is returns `null`

```
public function __construct() {

var_dump(session('cart'));

$this->cart = session('cart');
$this->payment = session('payment');
$this->coupon = session('coupon');

$this->currency = \App\Setting::where('key','eur_currency')->first()->value;

if (!isset($this->cart["items"])) {
  $cart = ['items' => [],'total' => 0, 'sub_total' => 0,'try' => 0];
  session(['cart' => $cart]);
  $this->cart = session('cart');
} 
....
....
....
```

How can i access sessions in `__constructor` method?

Edit: Thanks for @devk, my method working now.

```
public function __construct() {
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
  $this->cart = session('cart');
  $this->payment = session('payment');
  $this->coupon = session('coupon');

  $this->currency = \App\Setting::where('key','eur_currency')->first()->value;

  if (!isset($this->cart["items"])) {
    $cart = ['items' => [],'total' => 0, 'sub_total' => 0,'try' => 0];
    session(['cart' => $cart]);
    $this->cart = session('cart');
  }


  if (!isset($this->coupon["applied"])) {
    $coupon = ['applied' => false,'code' => null,'type' => null, 'value' => null];
    session(['coupon' => $coupon]);
    $this->coupon = session('coupon');
  }

  if (!isset($this->payment["payment_type"])) {
    $payment = ['payment_type' => 'CC', 'invoice_type' => 'PERSONAL',   'invoice' => [ 'fullname' => '','email' => '','company' => '','tax_office' => '','tax_id' => '' ]];
    session(['payment' => $payment]);
    $this->payment = session('payment');
  }

  return $next($request);
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.3 you are no longer able to access session in controller constructors, [because middleware has not run yet](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-session-in-constructor).

[You can define a closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0) (scroll to "Session In The Constructor") that happens after the session middleware has run.